# Convexity/concavity of the IRR function under specific assumptions

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, finance

Consider a fixed upfront investment at $t_0=0$ and wlog assume the cashflow to be $-1$. And assume the subsequent returns on this investment are all positive, i.e., a series of positive cashflows $c_{i}>0$ that happens at $t_i > t_0$ where $0=t_0<t_1<\cdots<t_n<\infty$. Now treat all $t_i$ as fixed, but treat $c_i>0$ as variables. Then IRR $r$ corresponding to $(c_1,\cdots,c_n)$ can be defined by
$$\sum_i \frac{c_i}{(1+r)^{t_i}}=1$$
So $r$ is an implicit function in $(c_1,\cdots,c_n)\in\Bbb R_n^+$. Is there any guarantee on the convexity/concavity of $r$ under the following assumptions respecitively:

1). $0<t_1<\cdots<t_n\le 1$.

2). $1 <t_1<\cdots<t_n<\infty$.

3). No further assumptions on $t_i$.

From 1D heuristics I believe $r$ is convex under 1) and concave under 2) and indetermined under 3). Are there any easy ways to prove these guesses?

---

The comment by @Raskolnikov sugggests that these conditions are probably not enough to characterise convexity/concavity.

Comment: I think it's not true, I constructed a counter-example to 2) being concave: $$\frac{x}{\left(1+y\right)^{1.01}}+\frac{b}{\left(1+y\right)^{2}} + \frac{a}{\left(1+y\right)^{3}}=1$$, take $a=5, b=1$ fixed and make a y-x plot and you'll see that it is not concave.

Comment: @Raskolnikov you're right. I tried it on WolframAlpha and it seems to be convex. Maybe my scenarios are not enough to characterise the boundary between the convex/concave regions.

Answer (score 1):

It seems even the one dimensional case is not as clear cut:

Take $1<t_1<t_2<t_3$, $c_1=c_2=c_3=c$ and thus

$$\frac{1}{\left(1+r\right)^{t_1}}+\frac{1}{\left(1+r\right)^{t_2}} + \frac{1}{\left(1+r\right)^{t_3}}=\frac{1}{c} \; .$$

One can then find relationships $r(c)$ that are neither convex nor concave for appropriate choices of the times. Here's an example I have constructed with the help of the Desmos calculator:

[image: Graph of the relation]

Also, this may be a trivial remark, but the fact you order the times is irrelevant, because the terms in the sum are interchangeable anyway.

Comment: by one dimensional i meant there is only one future cash flow $c_1>0$ i.e. the function $r$ takes a scalar.

Comment: Yes, but I extended it to a constant cashflow over time (except zero values which don't contribute).

Comment: Your previous example in your comment has already invalidated my conditions as sufficient convexity characterisers. I'll try to post an updated version of conditions and discuss if its going to work out.

Comment: Also, it's easy to compute the second order derivative $dr/dc$ to see why it does not necessarily work. And maybe specify conditions where it could work.